# Принципиально ли различие версий Debian?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

У меня на VPS стоит Debian 7.9 (64), хочу у себя на компе установить на VirtualBox всё тоже самое, чтобы без проблем доделать сайт и потом перенести на VPS.

Если я у себя на компе установлю Debian 8.5 (64) то по идее может же быть такой момент, что на компе работает все нормально, а на VPS - нет? Или вероятность мала и не париться ставить 8.5?

сайт python 2.7 + djanjo + oscar

Comment: А вы по каким-то идеологическим причинам не хотите ставить 7.9? Что склоняет именно в сторону 8.5?

Comment: нет, скорее по тому, что не могу найти на официальном сайте. Только на торрентах

Comment: Плохо ищете, [вот архив](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/) :)

Comment: Благодарю, да действительно))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это больше зависит от того, какие пакеты в **Debian** вы используете.

**В общем случае такая ситуация очень даже возможна.** Скорее теоретически, но всё же.

Если пользоваться **Debian 8** и сильно рассчитывать на новые пакеты, после миграции на **Debian 7** можно обнаружить, что каких-то пакетов в официальных репозиториях там нет. Совсем.

Скорее всего, им **можно** будет найти замену. Скорее всего, это даже будет не очень сложно. Но **может** потребоваться обновить и зависимости. Собрать что-то из исходников. В общем, **"худший случай"** может в себя включать много приключений, но у него мало шансов.

---

Ваши сомнения были бы понятны, если бы ваша система для разработки была на Debian 8 и вам было бы жалко работать **не** на ней. Но если вы всё равно собрались ставить систему в VirtualBox, то лучше поставить **ту же самую**  версию ОС, которую ожидаете на сервере. Так ожидания будут гораздо лучше стыковаться с действительностью.

Ах да, самое главное.
У Debian есть [**архив образов старых версий**](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/). Нужную вам версию можно взять там.